# About JazzyListView Android

Tags: java, android, listview, animation, jazzylistview

When I implement JazzyListView library, I was getting an error like:

```
com.nineoldandroids cannot be resolved

The type CardsEffect must implement the inherited abstract method JazzyEffect.setupAnimation(View, int, int, ViewPropertyAnimator)

ViewHelper cannot be resolved

ViewPropertyAnimator cannot be resolved to a type
```

I just wanted to implement JazzyListView  in my project:

- Reference link: https://github.com/twotoasters/jazzylistview
- See on apk file: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample

Anybody can help me, please....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hay i just got the answer.....in order to resolve this .....you need to add one more project as library which is [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids)

make sure that all these project are in the same directory.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you add dependencies in build.gradle ?

```
compile 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library:1.2.1'
compile 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library-recyclerview:1.2.1'
```